# Clickable DIV with children links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a clickable `div` element that has a few links inside it. When I click anywhere on the `div` the page will go to the mail link but I want to be able to go to all the other links inside that `div`. I have managed to do this by calling the `e.stopPropagation();` method. This works very good. You can see it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nfZ3y/1/

The problem is, when hold the `ctrl` key and click on the link (to open it on a new tab), the link will not work and the page will go to the default link (instead of the one that I just clicked on). How can I achive all of the functionalities of the child links and add a default link for my `div`?

Comment: Just wanted to point out, it works in Chrome.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. When I ctrl-click on any link, it opens a new window to the expected website.

Comment: Maybe it only fails in older browsers? It doesn't work in FF3.6, but it does in every other browser I tested (Chrome, Opera, Safari)

Comment: Ctrl-click on the links doesn't work for me in FF 10.0.2 (XP Home). It doesn't even go to the default link.

Comment: FF 9.0 is not working. It looks like FF has the problem.

Comment: Thanks people. Because of the Firebug, I'm testing my website in Firefox first. I didn't test it on other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people pointed out, it seems `stopPropagation` works differently in Firefox from the other browsers. My only suggestion is handling the click yourself:

```
$('.first').click(function (e) {
    var title = $(this).children('.main-link');
    var href = title.attr('href');
    if ( e.ctrlKey )
        window.open(href,"_blank");
    else
        window.location = href;
    return false;
});

$('.first a').click(function (e) {
    var title = $(this);
    var href = title.attr('href');
    if ( e.ctrlKey )
        window.open(href,"_blank");
    else
        window.location = href;
    return false;
});​
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/ATrWP/) on jsFiddle.

**Update:** for less redundancy, substitute the first handler for this:

```
$('.first').click(function (e) {
    $(this).children('.main-link').click();
    return false;
});
```